# UIButton as part of UITableViewCell subview - make it work

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm having some class which is a subclass of UITableViewController.
on one of the TableView's cell I'm adding a view that holds a UIButton as subview
(i.e. [someParentView addsubview:button])
I'm adding the view to cell like this:
[cell.contentView addSubview:someParentView]

I've set the UserInteractionEnabled both for the button and for the view holding it ("someParentView") to YES
but still when I tap it, nothing seems to be happening.

any idea?

Thanks

---

What i want to accomplish in short: i want to make a tableview that shows some views.
each view contains some subviews, and in one of those cases there is a uibutton as a subview.
i want to have this button to trigger event by user's tap, as any other uibutton, so some method will be launched.

to do that, i made a class which subclasses UITableViewController, and for each cell i added a view using [cell.contentView someView], as i wrote. i disabled selection from all using the [self.tableview setAllowSelection:NO] and for each sell made selection style as NONE.
as said, i also set the view and the uibutton UserInteractionEnabled property to YES.
anything i'm missing?

Comment: could you elaborate on what you expect to happen, and how you think you accomplished this?

Comment: i add it as an answer, 'cause it's to long for a comment.

Comment: user clipsToBounds to check if that button is within the correct area.

Answer (score 1):

Been solved!
I have used the method:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

of `UIView` class in my subclass and returned the button as the returned object.
(of course, needed to test point if in button area).